# ¿Por qué no llega una notificación cuando la app está abierta?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

Buenas noches 
llevo ya varios dias con este problema
solo me llega la notificación cuando la app
esta cerrada pero cuando esta abierta no
y no se que hacer....por favor
si me pueden ayudar les debo media vida gracias

```
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {


        //en este metodo se recibe la notificacion
        String from = remoteMessage.getFrom();
        Log.e("DE: ", from);
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody() != null) {
            Log.e("CUERPO", remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());


            showNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.e("DATA", "DATA" + remoteMessage.getData());

        }
    }

    private void showNotification(String title, String body) {
        // Patrón de vibración: 1 segundo vibra, 0.5 segundos para, 1 segundo vibra
        System.out.println("natalia " +body+""+ title);

        long[] pattern = new long[]{1000,500,1000};

        //metodo que se encaraga  de mostrar la notificacion y de adicionarle determinadas caracteristicas
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
     //   intent.putExtra("notificacion",body);
        PendingIntent pendingintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificadorBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(soundUri)
                .setLights(DEFAULT_LIGHTS,100,100)
                .setVibrate(pattern)
                .setContentIntent(pendingintent);

        NotificationManager notificacationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificacationManager.notify(0, notificadorBuilder.build());
```

este es mi clase que recibe la notificacion por favor ayuda

Comment: Me parece extraño lo que comentas, la ejecución de onHandleIntent() es independiente a si esta cerrada o abierta la aplicación. Asegura este sucediendo lo que comentas, agrega un breakpoint en el método que comento.

Comment: Revisa el LogCat para saber si ocurre algún error.

Comment: ¿Y si le pones un flag diferente de este: `FLAG_ONE_SHOT`? FLAG_ONE_SHOT:  Flag indicating that this PendingIntent can be used only once. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html

Comment: Lo estoy probando en un tablet lenovo no se si eso tendra algo que ver

Comment: Buenas noches... ya probe pero no me funciona sigue igual cunado la app esta abierta no me llegan las notificaciones.....no se que hacer

Comment: intenta agregando `.setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)` despues de tu `.setSound(soundUri)`

Comment: Pudiste solucionar tu error? a mi me pasa lo mismo

Answer (score 0):

> ¿Por qué no llega una notificación cuando la app está abierta?
>   al ser llamado el método onMessageReceived() y crear tu notificación es independiente si la aplicación esta abierta o cerrada.

El problema parece ser el flag definido en el [PendingIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html)

```
 PendingIntent pendingintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

> [FLAG_ONE_SHOT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_ONE_SHOT) : Bandera que indica que este PendingIntent puede
>   utilizarse sólo una vez.

Puedes optar por no usar un Flag especifico, con esto el PendingIntent no tendrá problemas en mostrarse más de una ocasión.

```
 PendingIntent pendingintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
```

Comment: No aun no me funciona.....

Comment: Y lo peor es que no me saca error

Comment: Hay algo importante que revisar, tu dispositivo esta configurado para que destruya las actividades?

Comment: disculpa prodrias ser mas especifico Jorgesys no entiendo a que te refieres con destruir las actividades

Comment: Tienes activadas las opciones de desarrollo  en tu dispositivo? https://i.stack.imgur.com/WL1oY.png ahí puedes configurar que se destruyan las activities, eso puede ser causa del problema

Comment: si claro tengo las opciones de desarrollador habilitadas para poder emular  la aplicacion

Comment: La opción "Don´t keep activities" o "no mantener actividades" esta desactivada?

Comment: si la tengo desactivada...no se que es lo que pasa

Comment: por favor ayuda

Comment: @natalia Has revisado el LogCat ? es importate revisar si se encuentra un mensaje.

Comment: si ahora si me esta sacando error cuando llega la notificacion https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2-tz3T8CU4OWnpGaHYwZzFMQmc

Comment: l] getToken() -> BAD_AUTHENTICATION. Account: <ELLIDED:559049996>, App: com.google.android.gms, Service: oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contextcontroller

Comment: esta es la imagen del error https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2-tz3T8CU4OWnpGaHYwZzFMQmc

Comment: Por favor ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que crear un canal para las versiones Oreo en adelante, ejecuta este método al iniciar tu APP.

```
private void createNotificationChannel() {
     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
         CharSequence name = getString(R.string.channel_name);
         String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
         NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("mnsChanel1", name, 
                                              NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
         channel.setDescription(description);
         NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService
                                                  (NotificationManager.class);
         notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
}
```

Después en tu método onMessageReceived

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            mayorOreo(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(),
                      remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }else{
            menorOreo(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(),
                      remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }
    }
}
```

Los métodos para distintas versiones

```
public void mayorOreo(String titulo, String body){
     String id = "Chanel1";
     NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)
                              getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
     NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,id);
          builder.setAutoCancel(true)
              .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
              .setContentTitle(titulo)
              .setContentText(body)
              .setContentIntent(click())
              .setContentInfo("new")
              .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
          nm.notify(0,builder.build());
}
public void menorOreo(String titulo, String body){
     String id = "Chanel1";
     NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) 
                              getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
     NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, id)
             .setAutoCancel(true)
             .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
             .setContentTitle(titulo)
             .setContentText(body)
             .setContentIntent(click())
             .setContentInfo("new")
             .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
     nm.notify(0,builder.build());
}
```

Metodo PendingIntent

```
public PendingIntent click(){
    Intent notify = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    notify.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    return PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,notify,0);
}
```